# Android adapter with GridView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, adapter, oncreate

I created a soundboard with a `GridView` adapter, but I'm getting two issues.

1. It says

> "CustomGridAdapter cannot be applied"

`myGridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items));`

2. It says

> "Cannot resolve method itemClicked(int)"

```
              ` @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.itemClicked(position);
                }
            });`
```

Here is my mFragment.java file:

```
package com.aaron.waller.girdlayoutmanagertest.mFragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.aaron.waller.girdlayoutmanagertest.MainActivity;
import com.aaron.waller.girdlayoutmanagertest.R;

public class erstesFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView gridView;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    public String[] items ={"Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4","Button5","Button6"};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.erstes_fragment,container,false);


        gridView= (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items));

        return rootView;
    }
    public void itemClicked(int position) {

        if(position == 0){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound1);
            mp.start();
        }else if(position == 1){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound2);
            mp.start();

        }else if(position == 2) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound3);
            mp.start();
        }
        else if(position == 3) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound4);
            mp.start();
        }
        else if(position == 4) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound5);
            mp.start();
        }
        else if(position == 5) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound6);
            mp.start();
        }

    }

    public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private MainActivity context;
        private String[] items;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity context, String[] items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            }
            Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setText(items[position]);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.itemClicked(position);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

How can I solve this two issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Replace this:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items));
```

With:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(this, items));
```

2) In CustomAdapter modify as following:

```
    private Context context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both did't helped :(

Comment: I removed the itemClicked method and pasted it into my MainActivity, so the seconds issue was solved, then I pasted this line in my Fragment: `public  MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity() ;` this solved the first issue. But my application won't open now :( And the Logcat is showing nothing, for whatever reason.

Comment: "But my application won't open now" means your app is crashing. There has to be something in the logcat. Please clear and restart logcat then try debugging again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 gridView.setAdapter(new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), items));
```

in `CustomGridAdapter` class

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomGridAdapter(Context c, String[] items) {
        this.context = c;
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Now for the click listener use:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(context instanceof MainActivity) {
                    ((MainActivity) context).itemClicked(position);
                }
            }
        });
```